# How to avoid loading relationship attributes if object is not persistent in SQLAlchemy session when caching from pickled object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy joined table inheritance for two tables: User and Employee. 
I implemented my own 'get' method which uses Redis as cache to store objects as pickle, and also implemented my own serialize method to create json responses. When I get the pickled User object and try to serialize it, I get an error 'instance is not bound to a session' because the query returns an Employee object instead of User, and the serialize method tries to query for relationship attributes like employee.team_id. I can't merge the object to the session because it's a costly operation and I need to rely on my cache for serving responses.

I set relationships to load eagerly, so that the object gets pickled and stored in cache with all of its relational values (e.g employee.team which realtes to the Team table). 
The Employee.get method and its serialize method work ok, but when I try to use the User.get method, it returns Employee objects instead of User objects because of the polymorphic identity, and it doesn't load the Employee attributes because the User table doesn't include them. 
If the returned object class is Employee, while serializing it tries to get the team attribute and throws an erorr "Instance  is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed", because the pickled object came from a User query and it doesn't eagerly load the Employee attributes.

My question is, is there a way to get User objects when querying the User table so that my User.get method uses it's corresponding serialize method? Or alternatively, can I prevent an object from getting relationship attributes (like employee.team) if the object is not persistent in session?

## Here's the User class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # Basic user data
    id = db.Column(db.GUID(), default=uuid.uuid4(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), index=True)
    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_types.id'))
    type = db.relationship('UserType', back_populates='users', lazy='subquery')
    password = db.Column(db.String(40), default=None)
    # Basic contact info
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, default=None)
    # Personal info
    birth_date = db.Column(db.Date(), index=True, default=None)
    birth_city = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, default=None)
    rfc = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, default=None)
    curp = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, default=None)
    address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('addresses.id'), default=None)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 1,
        'polymorphic_on': type_id
    }
```

## The UserType class for polymorphic identity:

```
class UserType(db.Model):
    """
    Create a UserType table
    """
    __tablename__ = 'user_types'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', back_populates='type', lazy='select')

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "name": self.name
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<UserType: {self.id} - {self.name}>'
```

## The Employee class:

```
class Employee(User):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'
    # Basic employee data
    id = db.Column(db.GUID(), db.ForeignKey('users.id'), default=uuid.uuid4(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    # Operation info
    goal = db.Column(db.Integer, db.CheckConstraint('goal>=0'), default=0)
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    team = db.relationship('Team', back_populates='employees', lazy='subquery')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 2
    }
```

## And the Team class:

```
class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(30))
    # eagerly load the team attribute
    employees = db.relationship('Employee', back_populates='team', lazy='select')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Team: {}>'.format(self.name)
```

## The get method is a classmethod inside the User class, the Employee

## class inherits from this, that's why it uses cls.query for querying:

```
@classmethod
def list(cls, args):
    cache_key = f'{cls.__name__}s:{build_key_from_arguments(**args)}'
    cache = redis_db.get(cache_key)
    if cache:
        return None, cls.pickle_load(cache)
    else:
        query = cls.query.filter(
                cls.visible == True
            )
        # More filters...
        data = query.all()
        redis_db.set(cache_key, pickle.dumps(data, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) if data else REDIS_LIST_NONE)
        return data
```

## Finally, the serialize methods look this way, each class has its own:

## User serialize has its core attributes

```
@property
def serialize(self):
    obj = {
        "id": str(self.id),
        "username": self.username,
        "type": self.type.serialize,
        "status": self.status.serialize,
        "role": self.role.serialize,
        "first_name": self.first_name,
        "last_name": self.last_name,
        "email": self.email
    }
    return obj
```

## Employee serialize adds its own attributes if they exist

```
@property
def serialize(self):
    obj = {
        "id": str(self.id),
        "username": self.username,
        "type": self.type.serialize,
        "status": self.status.serialize,
        "role": self.role.serialize,
        "first_name": self.first_name,
        "last_name": self.last_name,
        "email": self.email
    }
    if self.team_id:
        obj['team'] = self.team.serialize
    return obj
```

When I do the following:

```
users = User.list({})
```

(users is a list of Employee objects)

```
[user.serialize for user in users]
```

It works the first time, when the actual query is made, but the second time when it retrieves data from Redis, the pickled objects are not in session and throws a "Instance  is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed".

The expected output would be a list of dictionaries of serialized User objects.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by adding

```
'polymorphic_load': 'inline'
```

to Employee class in **mapper_args**